# Use 'this' keyword to call the base constructor and using method calls to set the private members

Tags: java

Just a few questions:

1) If you have a super class Monster and you create a subclass that inherits its behaviour. Its it good practice to call `super` in every constructor in the `subclass`. What I have done below is call it once in the first overloaded constructor and in the second overloaded constructor I call the first using `this(..)` Is this the best practice?

2) Is it better to use the method calls i.e `setHealthAid(10)` to set the class fields of use assignment instead i.e.

```
mHealthAid = -1;
mHasInvisibleMode = false;
```

class snippet without the implementation of getters and setters to make this short.

```
public class Monster {  
    private int mStrength;  
    private int mScareFactor;   

    public Monster(int strength, int scareFactor) {     
        setStrength(strength);      
        setScareFactor(scareFactor);    
    }   

    /* Getters and setters */
}

public class BigBoss extends Monster {  
    private int mHealthAid; 
    private boolean mHasInvisibleMode;  

    public BigBoss(int strength, int scareFactor) {     
        super(strength, scareFactor);       
        setHealthAid(-1);       
        setHasInvisibleMode(false);     
    }       
    public BigBoss(int strength, 
                   int scareFactor, 
                   int healthAid, 
                   boolean hasInvisibleMode) {      
       this(strength, scareFactor);     
       setHealthAid(healthAid);     
       setHasInvisibleMode(hasInvisibleMode);   
    }   

    /* Getters and setters */
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: This should be on the code review network. That is where we put working code to ask if there is a 'better' way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) If you have a super class Monster and you create a subclass that
>   inherits its behaviour. Its it good practice to call super in every
>   constructor in the subclass. What I have done below is call it once in
>   the first overloaded constructor and in the second overloaded
>   constructor I call the first using this(..) Is this the best practice?

You should have one constructor, which takes all parameters required to properly instantiate class. In second constructor with fewer parameters,  you should use `this` to invoke first constructor and should pass default values for the missing parameters. Like:

```
public BigBoss(int strength, int scareFactor) {     
    this(strength, scareFactor, -1, false);
}       

//costructor with all required params to instantiate BigBoss properly  
public BigBoss(int strength, 
               int scareFactor, 
               int healthAid, 
               boolean hasInvisibleMode) {
   super(strength, scareFactor);     
   mHealthAid = healthAid;     
   mHasInvisibleMode = hasInvisibleMode;   
}
```

> 2) Is it better to use the method calls i.e setHealthAid(10) to set
>   the class fields of use assignment instead

You can use setters of fields from within the same class to set properties. But since you are already in the same class, you should directly use property to set values ie.

```
mHealthAid = -1;
mHasInvisibleMode = false;
```

This makes code a bit concise and you get small performance gain as no method call is involved.

Answer (score 1):

That will work but is kind of inefficient because you're calling the `setHealthAid(...)` and `setHasInvisibleMode(...)` method twice when the second constructor is used. What you can do instead is this:

```
public BigBoss(int strength, int scareFactor) {
   this(strength, scareFactor, -1, false);    
}       
public BigBoss(int strength, 
               int scareFactor, 
               int healthAid, 
               boolean hasInvisibleMode) {  
   super(strength, scareFactor);     
   setHealthAid(healthAid);     
   setHasInvisibleMode(hasInvisibleMode);   
}
```